# How to make this, when we type ab in textified then display applebanana as a single word ? in flutter

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

When type "ab" like this then should display applebanana,
[image]

Here it is my code
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it fixed that the key value of the map is one character?

Comment: avoid posting code-image, use code-snippet instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare each character of the text of `onChanged`, and if it is the same as `key` of `map`, add `value` and `setState` to update the UI.

```
final map = {
    "a": "apple",
    "b": "banana",
    "p": "pineapple"
  };

  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              onChanged: (String text){
                controller.text = "";
                for(int i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
                  if (i + 1 >= text.length) {
                    if (map[text[i]] != null) {
                      controller.text += map[text[i]]!;
                      print(controller.text);
                    }
                  }else{
                    if (map[text[i] + text[i + 1]] != null) {
                      controller.text += map[text[i] + text[i + 1]]!;
                      print(controller.text);
                    } else {
                      if (map[text[i]] != null) {
                        controller.text += map[text[i]]!;
                        print(controller.text);
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 10),

            Text(controller.text != "" ? controller.text : ""),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: It's working! Thank you bro ! and also how to give if have map size is two or three then . Ex:- "bl": "blueberries","ch": "cherries", "b":"banana"

Comment: @TharinduDasun It has been modified to be possible even when the length of the key value of the map is 1 or 2.